# How do I know which dealer for ATS Cars?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

I downloaded [Porsche Cayenne Turbo S 2016 v1.2 (1.34.x) ATS](http://www.modsats.com/porsche-cayenne-turbo-s-2016-v1-2-1-34-x-ats/) which stipulates

> – Buy at Volvo dealer

and [BMW X6M WITH TRAILER MOD](http://www.modsats.com/bmw-x6m-trailer-mod/) which doesn't stipulate the dealer.

How can I find out which:

1. which Volvo dealer? [This Reddit post](https://redd.it/9p9u0r) lists multiple.
2. which dealer to buy the BMW?

I'm a tyro, as I downloaded ATS today.